# event not being fired

Tags: c#, silverlight, events

I have made a custom dialog window that inherits ChildWindow

```
public partial class InputWindow : ChildWindow
{
    public InputWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("clicked");
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
    }

    private void inputTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            this.OKButton_Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
    }
}
```

When I press enter in the tetxbox the event `OKButton_Click` gets fired ( because message box appears). However, the code (Add Folder) in the event handler below that exists in another class does not get fired! even though the message box appears! Why is this so? and How can I fix it?

```
InputWindow win = new InputWindow();
win.Title = "Enter New Folder Name";
win.OKButton.Click += (s, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(win.inputTextBox.Text))
    {
        AddNewFolder(win.inputTextBox.Text);
        win.DialogResult = true;
    }
};
win.Show();
```

Comment: How is your xaml, because you don't attach the keydown event.

Comment: `<TextBox MaxLength="50" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,12,0,0" Name="inputTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" KeyDown="inputTextBox_KeyDown" />`

Comment: See the answer by @Jon Skeet + you need to call click event:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734482/button1-performclick-in-wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just calling `OKButton_click` directly from your `KeyDown` event handler. That's *not* the same as raising the `Click` event on the OK button itself - it's just a method call. So it's no wonder that other event handlers for `OKButton.Click` aren't being called.

I don't know of any way of manually raising the `Click` event yourself. It sounds like really you should have one common method which is called from both the `Click` event handler and the `KeyDown` event handler.