# Button Click On App Start

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a function inside of a button that I want to trigger as soon as my application starts, and I am doing it by this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

//get button reference

        Button btn = ((MainWindow)Current.MainWindow).btnJSON;

//programmatically simulate button click

        ButtonAutomationPeer peer =
          new ButtonAutomationPeer(btn);
        IInvokeProvider invokeProv =
          peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke)
          as IInvokeProvider;
        invokeProv.Invoke();
    }
}
```

However, this leads be to a `nullReferenceExeption`. How do I achieve this, i.e. invoking the fucntion on App stratup or simulate the button click?

Here is the button signature:

```
public void btnJSON_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what's happening in that first code block. Having said that, in WPF you can simulate a click on a button using `RaiseEvent`. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734482/button1-performclick-in-wpf

Comment: commented the code for better legibility.

Comment: No I could read it, I just meant it's very convoluted. You only need a single line to simulate the button click. However, I can also suggest that if you are simulating a button click on startup, to perform some operation, it would make much more sense to simply perform that operation on startup, rather than starting that operation with a simulated button-click.

Comment: Do you really have to actually click the button? Why not just call the same method that's called when the button is clicked?

Comment: @DrewJordan That is the skill I lack, how do I make the button's event visible to my App.cs? Thanks.

Comment: @pay Is it really possible to simulate button click in single line? `btn.PerformClick` no longer works I think.

Comment: Whatever set of operations you want to perform on that button click, should not go inside the button click event handler. Put that logic into it's own function, or several functions, and call that from the event handler. Similarly, you would call this function on startup.

Comment: @jeet Have you actually read my comments? I linked you a post that contains the single line to perform the button click... Please make sure you're reading people's comments thoroughly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to invoke the button click, just call the method that the button click invokes.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainWindow)Current.MainWindow).DoStuff();
    }
}
```

In your MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    // TODO: Do Stuff
}
```

Just have your button click handler call that method.

```
public void btnJSON_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     DoStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call the button click if all you want is to run some code. If your button's click handler looks like:

```
public void btnJSON_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     DoSomeInterestingStuff();
}
```

Then just call that method from your startup method:

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomeInterestingStuff();
    // other stuff to do here
}
```